# Are Superblock and Master File Tables the same thing?

Tags: ntfs, superblock

What is the difference between a superblock and a Master File Table (MFT)? Both seem to be tables that keep track of files within a filesystem, but are there other differences? The only difference I found was that the first is used for Ext4 filesystems and the other for NTFS filesystems, but are there any others?

Answer (score 1):

From a strict point of view they're obviously **not** the "same thing" - you can't swap them - so the strict answer is "no".

But the purpose of both is similar (by no means identical), so in a sense yes, you could say they're "the same thing".

But the overall purpose (of managing the file system) is accomplished differently in Ext2/3/4 and NTFS, so the superblock and the FAT aren't really equivalent.

Apart from the structure and data stored within, perhaps the simplest difference is that the MFT has a single, *partial* backup in [$MFTMIRROR](https://whereismydata.wordpress.com/2009/06/05/forensics-what-is-the-mft-mirror/), while the superblock has several complete backups throughout the partition.

Another obvious difference (due to the different kind of information stored) is their respective size. A subtler difference is the fact that MFT is [*file based*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/master-file-table) (so it can, say, get *fragmented*) while the superblock is at the block group hierarchy level.

Answer (score 0):

All filesystems will have semi-similar structures, but no, "superblock" is "superblock", and MFT is MFT, and there is no real overlap between them.

Most "modern" filesystems (including both ext4 and NTFS) are derived from Fast Berkeley Filesystem - FFS - so I suggest you hit google and wikipedia and study that first. Once you understand FFS, you can start to learn where ext4 and NTFS differs from both FFS and among themselves.

With some very strong stretching it could be said that FFS/EXT4 superblock is semi-equivalent to first/head block of MFT, and MFT is roughly equivalent to FFS cylinder/block group, but there are more nuanced differences, which make the two very, very different things.

For example there are often several cylinder groups, while there are only two (and even then non equivalent!) MFTs.

One of the most important difference between FFS/EXT4 and NTFS is, that in UNIX unique file IDs are essentially just numbers(!) - so called inodes. So all the files on unix storage have no names, only numbers/inodes! And that is the most important fact for you to remeber.

But NTFS is name based instead, and as was already said, files in NTFS thus must have names.

So, at those levels FFS and NTFS cannot even be compared together.

Now you might ask, where are the names you read on console in UNIX even coming from, right? Well filename is basically name of a row in a directory table of some directory, which is simply pointing to a given inode. Thus in UNIX, same file can have multiple names, it can even exist in multiple directories at the same time. As long as all directory row records point to same inode, they all point to same file.

Such organization is impossible in NTFS (but there are other ways to emulate something similar).

Finally, for example ZFS has "uberblock" and structure that is completely alien to FFS. So in ZFS "uberblock" is neither "superblock" nor MFT head, because ZFS structures do not map to anything to FFS at all.

What would be "uberblock" in NTFS, FFS or ext4? There is none.